# C++ API declaration fail with Cython

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, g++, cython

I have two files `module.pyx` and `foo.cpp`. I want to be able to call a function, declared in the cython module `module.pyx`, within `foo.cpp`. This function returns a pointer to a vector:

`module.pyx`:

```
#distuils: language = c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref

cdef api vector[int] *func():
    cdef vector[int] *v = new vector[int]()
    deref(v).push_back(3)
    return v
```

`foo.cpp`:

```
#include "module_api.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    import_module();
    vector<int> *v = func();
    cout << "v[0] = " << v[0] << endl;
}
```

I've compiled `module.pyx` with

`cython module.pyx --cplus`

and `foo.cpp` with

`g++ foo.cpp -I/Users/richizy/anaconda/include/python2.7/`

but it is not working. I get a huge error stating "vector in namespace 'std' does not name a type", among many other things. What is the problem?

I am using the Anaconda Python distribution, which I just did a recent clean & default install.

Versions:

> g++ (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.3_3+universal) 4.7.3
>
> Cython version 0.20.1
>
> Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.9.1 (x86_64)
>
> Mac OS X 10.8.4

Comment: Exchanging the two lines `#include "module_api.h"` and `#include <vector>` solve the problem with vector for me but then I got segfault. However I'm not able the get the `delorean` example from the doc working so I must have something else wrong.

Comment: Hi again Hivert. After wandering around Google, I think my bug is because of a forgotten linkage to the Python library (in my case, it's  located in `/Users/richizy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a`). But still, I get a seg fault as you say.

Comment: The segfault could be from not dereferencing the vector before accessing it. do `(*v)[0]` instead of `v[0]` in the c++ file.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like it is failing when it imports the module. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use the python engine from a C or C++ application,
you need to make sure that `Py_Initialize()` is called at the beginning
of your `main()` function, and that `Py_Finalize()` is called at the
end. What you also don't see is that the `import_module()` function
actually produces an error, but it does this using the python error
mechanism. You can make this visible by adding the following code
below `import_module()`:

```
if (PyErr_Occurred())
{
    PyErr_Print();
    return -1;
}
```

If you do that, you'll see the following error appear:

```
ImportError: No module named module
```

To be able to use a Cython module, you have to make sure
that that module's init function is called, in this case 
`initmodule()`. Unfortunatly it seems that the declaration of
this function is not present in the generated header file,
so we'll have to manually add it above the main:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC initmodule(void);
```

Together with placing the `vector` include line first and a small
fix in the `cout` line, the code then becomes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "module_api.h"

using namespace std;

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmodule(void);

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    initmodule();
    import_module();
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        return -1;
    }
    vector<int> *v = func();
    cout << "v[0] = " << (*v)[0] << endl;
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Which, at least on my system, produces the output:

```
v[0] = 3
```

Comment: I've replicated your code, but I'm getting an issue for `PyMODINIT_FUNC initmodule(void)` or `initmodule()`: 

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_initmodule", referenced from:
      _main in ccSkO2qw.o`

Does `initmodule` have to be implemented elsewhere, e.g. in `module_api.h`?

Comment: Nonetheless, if I remove `initmodule`, I'll replicate the same error msg: `ImportError: No module named module`

Comment: @richizy That 'initmodule' should be defined in the .cpp file generated from module.pyx